# How to setup sql adapter for oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Can anyone explain the steps to use a MobileFirst adapter to connect to an oracle database.The ibm tutorial have given steps and sample for mysql,but 
I need a basic sample  for oracle db.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the SQL adapter's XML with your values in the below example:

```
...
...
<connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
            <dataSourceDefinition>
                <driverClass>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClass>
                <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.148.227.20:1521:DB11G</url>
                <user>ram</user>
                <password>worklight</password> 
            </dataSourceDefinition>
        </connectionPolicy>
        ...
        ...
    </connectivity>
```

Be sure to also provide the Oracle driver and license files in the server/lib folder.

Comment: i get this error ?? i have copied ojdbc6.jar in server/lib of my project
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0035E: Invocation of procedure 'procedure1' failed. [project helloworld]
Class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver not found in Worklight platform or project /helloworld

Comment: sir now i am getting another error  "errors": [
      "Runtime: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)"

Comment: You have likely put the wrong details for the database. It doesn't find it.

Comment: other than this any changes required <dataSourceDefinition>
    <driverClass>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driverClass>
    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.***:****:****</url>
    <user>******</user>
    <password>****</password>
   </dataSourceDefinition>

Comment: 192.168 is an internal IP address; you should use your external IP address most likely.

Comment: thats the ip where my database is running

Comment: Something is misconfigured. It don't know what it is.